# Cant get access to an object's values of a cell in TableView [Swift]

Tags: swift, class, uitableview, object, tableview

I created a class called BlogPost and a tableView. The tableView get filled with many cells and each cell presents the data of a different user (a blogPost object). In each cell there's a button with a phone icon and I want that everytime the user presses on the phone button in each cell, it will call the number of the specific object in that cell. The problem is that in the button function there is no access to the objects value. The line:

```
var num = blogPost.phone
```

works inside the setBlogPost function, but not in the button function outside the setBlogPost function :

```
@IBAction func whatsAppButton(_ sender: Any) {
    //doesnt work
    var num = blogPost.phone
    openWhatsapp(number: num)
}
```

**num gets an error of "Use of unresolved identifier 'blogPost'.**

Full code:

```
import UIKit

class Tavla: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabelTavla: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationButtonTavla: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneButtonTavla: UIButton!
    fileprivate let application = UIApplication.shared

    func setBLogPost(blogPost: BlogPost) {

        nameLabelTavla.text = blogPost.name

        if blogPost.elsertext != "" {

                locationButtonTavla.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 135/255, green: 197/255, blue: 113/255, alpha: 0.5)
                locationButtonTavla.setTitle("", for: .normal)
            }
        else{
        }

        //num works fine
        var num = blogPost.phone
    }

    @IBAction func whatsAppButton(_ sender: Any) {
        //num gets an error of "Use of unresolved identifier 'blogPost'
        var num = blogPost.phone
        openWhatsapp(number: num)
    }


    func openWhatsapp(number: String){
        let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?phone=\(number)&abid=12354&text=לעדכן מיקום באפליקציה"
        if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
            if let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString) {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL)
                } else {
                    print("Install Whatsapp")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do actions like this in a UITableViewCell or any other UIViews.. Make a delegate or a closure push it back to a presenter/viewmodel or similar, and make that handle the OpenURL-stuff.. Views should be dumb, and only be told what to display - not handle any logic at all :) At least that's best practice imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `num` a member var:

```swift
class Tavla: UITableViewCell {
    var num: Int?

    // ...

    func setBLogPost(blogPost: BlogPost) {
        // ...
        num = blogPost.phone
    }

    @IBAction func whatsAppButton(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let num = num else { return }
        openWhatsapp(number: num)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

assign the blogPost id to button tag like

> button.tag = post.id

in **CellForItemAt** function, Now you have reference to the blogpost.You can get the clicked blogpost using the button tag like this

```
@IBAction func whatsAppButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let post = blogPostsArray.filter({$0.id == sender.tag})[0]
        var num = post.phone
        openWhatsapp(number: num)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just set `num` value in `setBlog` method as an inner variable. Then num variable can only access the `setBlog` method. And `blogPost` object can accessible on `setBlog` method, not in another method in this class. If you need to access `blogPost` object in this class then you need to maintain a variable in this class.

Like this:

```
class Tavla: UITableViewCell {
    var blogPost: BlogPost?
 ...

    func setBLogPost(blogPost: BlogPost) {
        self.blogPost = blogPost

         ....

        //num works fine
        var num = blogPost.phone // because it's access the param value
    }

    @IBAction func whatsAppButton(_ sender: Any) {
        // Now can access the blogPost variable on this class
        if let num = self.blogPost?.phone {
             openWhatsapp(number: num)
        }
    }

 }
```

Now the `blogPost` object can be accessible in `whatsAppButton` method.